# I want to be able to search a name I input and get a score

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to prompt the user to enter a specific student name and search the dictionary to display the student's score.

Here is what I have so far.

```
students = dict()
x = int(input('Enter the amount of students: '))
scores = []
for i in range(x):
    stuname = input(str('Enter student name: '))
    for j in range(1):
        score = float(input('enter scores: '))
        scores.append(score)
    students[stuname] = scores
    
print(sorted(students))
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: You're building a single `scores` list and setting the entire list as the value for each key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have one score for each student, I don't think you want to have a list at all -- instead have a dictionary that maps each student name to their score.

```
students = {
    input('Enter student name: '): float(input('Enter score: ')) 
    for _ in range(int(input('Enter the amount of students: ')))
}
```

which produces something like:

```
Enter the amount of students: 2
Enter student name: Sam
Enter score: 1
Enter student name: Bob
Enter score: 5
>>> students
{'Sam': 1.0, 'Bob': 5.0}
>>> students['Sam']
1.0
>>> print(students.get(input('Enter a student name: '), 'No such student.'))
Enter a student name: Sam
1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but after I enter a students name and scores I want to be able to type in a name of one student and get back their score

Comment: Do `students[name]` and you'll get their score.

Comment: I should have been more specific after I enter all the students and scores I want to create a prompt that will search the dictionary for one student and get their score.

Comment: `print(students.get(input('Enter a student name: '), 'No such student.'))`

Comment: I just want to double-check for when searching the dictionary I am supposed to use the key, val tuple assignment does the code above do that?

Comment: What would be the point of searching the dictionary if you had to provide the value?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new score list for each student. For that, you need to create `scores` inside the loop:

```py
students = dict()
x = int(input('Enter the amount of students: '))
for i in range(x):
    stuname = input(str('Enter student name: '))
  
    scores = []
    for j in range(1):
        score = float(input('enter scores: '))
        scores.append(score)
    students[stuname] = scores
    
print(sorted(students))
```